# Connection strings in .NET 6 Worker service

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, connection-string, .net-6.0, worker-service

I am trying to connect to database with connection string which is written in appsetting.json. I try to pass it in UseSqlServer("...") in AddDbContext but it just doesn't work. When I write it in Context class it works.
So, program runs without errors but it doesn't connect to Db.

Does someone know what is wrong here?
Below is Program.cs code:

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options =>
    {
        options.ServiceName = "Subscriber Service";
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<DeliveryService>()
            .AddSingleton<IQueueService, QueueService>()
            .AddSingleton<IMailTransport, MailTransport>()
            .AddSingleton<IHttpTransport, HttpTransport>()
            .AddDbContext<nbiot_core_svctestContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Comment: "it just doesn't work": any error message? Or output? Usually setting up connection string looks like `options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("key_name_in_appsettings"));`

Comment: Program runs without errors.
I just want to somehow get connection string in UseSqlServer() that is written in appsettings.json but I dont know how.
I found some solutions but those are all for older versions of .NET and I am using .NET 6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder.configureservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) accepts an action with two parameters, the first one is `HostBuilderContext` exposing configuration property (the one you are using comes from [`HostingHostBuilderExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.configureservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)), so try:

```
.ConfigureServices((ctx, services)=>
{
    services
        ...
        .AddDbContext<nbiot_core_svctestContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(ctx.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
})
```